# Does the order of elements change when list is converted into tuple?

Tags: python

In my problem, the order of elements in list has meaning. Hence, preserving its order is important.

e.g.) [102030, 101091] Company 102030 sells to Company 101091

I have two lists of such list.

> e.g.)

```
list1 = [[102030, 101091], [10102, 990], .....]
list2 = [[102030, 101091], [40102, 290], .....]`
```

Since, I want to do set operations like intersection, union, leaving only the unique element, I tried to make these two list into set.

However,

> set(list1) returns 
>   "unhashable type: 'list'"

Hence, I alternatively took the code below

```
set1 = set([tuple(item) for item in list1])    
set2 = set([tuple(item) for item in list2])
```

and do some set operations like set1&set2, set1|set2.

However, I am worried that changing list to tuple might have changed the order of its elements, like from [102030, 101091] to (101091, 102030).

My question is,

1. Does converting a list to a tuple change its order of elements?
2. If so is there any more pythonic way to do what I intended to do (leaving only the unique elements(elements whose type are list) and doing set operations)?

Comment: 1- No, 2- I don't think so

Comment: Is the actual issue how to intersect two lists while preserving order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Converting a list to a tuple will not change the order of the elements. Tuples are ordered, so are lists.
2. Yes, you can use [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) (rather than list comprehensions).

```py
set(tuple(item) for item in your_list)
```

Generator expressions do not build the list in memory, instead they iterate over elements one at a time (lazily). This makes them much faster than the list comprehensions.

Note that generator expressions are usually written as `generator = (tuple(item) for item in your_list)`, however, when used as the only argument for a function the brackets are omitted - it would look like this otherwise:

```py
set((tuple(item) for item in your_list))
```

This, of course, is prone to error.

You can alternatively use the `map()` function. This does the exact same thing (externally) as the generator expression above.

```py
set(map(tuple, your_list))
```

Comment: `map` is not recommended anymore. Finding a source for that. Mentioned in the RATIONALE of PEP 289 and by [this essay by Guido](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: It is probably a matter of opinion. You can use either, although I believe map is slightly slower when you have to define a lambda function.

Comment: Guido obviously changed his mind according to the update of the essay and PEP 289 only says "List comprehensions greatly reduced the need for filter() and map()" and similar for generator expressions and imap. Especially for a simple generator expression `f(item) for item in iterable` with just a simple constructor/function call, a `map(f, iterable)` is more concise and easy to read.

Comment: I'll mention it in the answer.

Comment: What is discouraged is using map with a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tuples and lists both support indexing and are ordered. Converting between them will not change this order.
2. There are one-line solutions that involve `map()` or other methods but your code is the most readable and it isn't too long, so I like it. If you want to one-line it without making it more complex you can just use a comma (don't do this if the lists are long):

   ```
   list1, list2 = [[102030, 101091], [10102, 990], .....], [[102030, 101091], [40102, 290], .....]
   ```